# Adding zeros to right or decimal

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have numbers like this

17.23
3.4
22

In my database. I want to display them as 17.23, 3.40, and 22.00. I tried to use `Round(my_column, 2)` but it didn't add the needed zero's. Right now I have this after applying google foo `To_Char(my_column, '999G999D00')`. Is there a way to do this and still leave the output as a number not a varchar.

Comment: You should only be applying that format at display time, so what would keeping it as a number achieve? Or is the output of the query being consumed by a client/application - in which case it should be left as a number and the client should format it with the trailing zeroes? SQL*Plus can apply a display format to a number but i don't think that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare them as `NUMBER(*,2)` or cast them to this type.

Comment: That won't change how the value is displayed, though?

Answer (score 0):

1. Substring until you find '.'
2. Right pad the string after the '.'
   In oracle you can use RPAD function for example.

   RPAD( '4', 2, [ '0' ] ) -> '40'
3. Concatenate

Exemple: 
SELECT SUBSTR('13.4', 0, INSTR('13.4', '.')) || RPAD(SUBSTR('13.4', INSTR('13.4', '.')+1, LENGTH('13.4')), 2, '0') AS output
  FROM DUAL